# How to copy subset of files in R

Tags: r, copy-paste

I have 260 files in the directory. The annotation of files is as Imxxx_y, where x is from 001 to 130 and y is 0 or 1. That is, for y=0, I have 130 files and the remaining 130 are for y=1. If I want to copy the first 100 files how can I do that in R? I tried the code as bellow,

`fnames <- list.files(path = original_dataset_dir, pattern = "1.tif")
file.copy(file.path(original_dataset_dir, fnames), 
          file.path(train1_yes_dir))`

It copies 130 files, But I want to copy just 100.

Comment: As they are numbered as you say, maybe the first 100 entries of "fnames" correspond to your desired 100 files. In that case, you could copy fnames[1:100] instead of fnames.

Comment: `fnames <- list.files(path = original_dataset_dir, pattern = "1.tif")[1 : 100]`?

Comment: can I subset like 1:20 and 40:80?

Comment: @Ehtasham Billah Mymun you can if that is what you want:
`fnames <- list.files(path = original_dataset_dir, pattern = "1.tif")[c(1 : 20, 40 : 80)]`

Comment: i don't think your question is clear enough: why do you only want the "first" 100 of `y = 1` subset? if the files you want are united by a specific property reflected in the file names, might be that there is a more elegant solution than subsetting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just try `system("cp this_dir/lm*_1.tif destination_dir/")`. This would work in a bash terminal. If you're in windows you'll have to use the equivalent command there.